# Let's Encrypts é possível certificar IPs?

Tags: ssl, certificado-digital, https

Tenho um servidor local rodando algumas aplicações `php`, e algumas rodando em ambiente virtual hosts, todos acessando via `https`, mas agora a empresa quer disponibilizar a intranet via ip para acesso externo, porém não querem registrar um domínio para apontar através dos dns registro.br, já li a documentação e não encontro uma solução, mas em alguns fóruns encontrei relato de pessoas que conseguiram, porém sem tutorial.

Alguém conseguiu certificar `Let's Encrypt` para ips públicos? como mencionei estou sem verba mesmo para um domínio, quanto menso para uma ssl. Ou existe outra forma de certificados gratuitos?

Este é meu cenário:

```
Servidor Linux: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS X64
2TB de HD
16 GB Ram
2MB link dedicado
```

Comment: Seria tão mais fácil apontar um subdomínio, não? Algo como intranet.dominioatualdaempresa.com.br, que custaria 15 minutos de configuração no máximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente no momento não é possível certificar sobre ip, somente por domínio, esta informação pode ser encontrada no site oficial do [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) e na comunidade do site neste [link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/wildcard-or-ip-based-cert/19476)

Mas segundo a documentação existe um estudo e estão em teste, vamos aguardar.